# Many to Many Table Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

So a quick question here, I have two tables within my database which is connected to a Yii2 web application.

My two tables are named attributes and people, I have a CRUD area for both of them so I can manipulate the the contents of each table separately.

The two tables are extremely simple at the moment and are structured as follows.

Attribute Table:

`attribute_id | attribute_name
------------------------------`

People Table:

`person_id | person_name
------------------------------`

Now the attribute names will be items like hair color, eye color, weight, etc

Now what I want is to be able to assign an attribute to a particular person with a value, for example if person1 existed, I want to assign hair color (Assuming hair color already exists as an attribute) with a value such as 'brown' to person1.

At the moment I kind of have a mental block and don't really know how to go forward from this point on, could anyone point me in the right direction or help me out here?

Cheers.

Comment: You need a junction table which will have user id and attribute id and value for user attribute so that each user can have different attributes its a many to many example

Comment: Thanks for the help, but for a junction table should you not only have the PK of the junction table and the two FK of the referenced tables? Is it possible to have a junction table with another column such as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another table

```
person_attributes
-----------------
person_id
attribute_id
value
```

Comment: Thanks, I thinks this is exactly what I am looking for, I will try to carry this forward in that manner.